# How can I fix this error even it was coded properly?

Tags: java, graphics

I need some help for my project in school. I put the code properly, but the error appears everytime I compile it in the cmd.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class bagangan2 extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
         setBackground(Color.yellow);

      g.drawString("Anita's Antiques",15,20);
      g.drawString("905 N. Van Buren",15,30);
      g.drawString("Albany, Missouri 64402",15,40);
      g.drawString("Anita'sAntiques@mallStore.com",15,50);
    }
 }
```

But I get the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>javac bagangan2.java
bagangan2.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
         g.setBackround(Color.yellow);
          ^
  symbol:   method setBackround(Color)
  location: variable g of type Graphics
1 error
```

I can't figure out this error.

Comment: The code you posted uses `setBackground()`, but the error complains about `setBackround()`. If the error is exactly that, you made a typo and the code in the question does not reflect your actual code. Please verify that and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on what is written in the error message, you just missed the letter "g" in the word "background", that is typed "back_round" instead. See:
g.setBackround(Color.yellow); ^ symbol: method setBackround(Color) location: variable g of type Graphics 1 error
But on the other hand, your code shows the properly written word "background":
g.setBackground(Color.yellow)
I don't know how it happened, but check your code one more time.

Comment: I properly edited the codes but the new error that showed is:

bagangan2.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
import java.
            ^
1 error